# Python: get the result of a request to to Javascript button

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Python code is to go to:
http://www.youtube-mp3.org/

Pass the form and convert button a link to a video and retrieve the resultant download link.

My python code:

```
page = 'http://www.youtube-mp3.org/'
video = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOMETHING"
session = requests.Session()
session = session.post('http://www.youtube-mp3.org/',data={'youtube-url': video})
soup= BeautifulSoup(session.text,'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link)
```

The problem is that even after passing the data to the convert button, the page is not reloaded and the source code remains the same, hence the download link is not in the source code and I do not know how to get it.

Comment: Should not you be parsing the result of `session.post()`?

Comment: I edited my code hoping that this is what you meant, however it still doesn't work.